# Hudson and Pre-Build jobs

Tags: hudson

I have a build job (A) and a functional test job (B), so the idea was that when clicking in B, Hudson would launch A before anything happens, failing if the build fails. The oposite is not true, clicking on A should not launch B.

I searched over and over, there are some plugin tips here concerning the Parameterized Plugin. But I couldn't get it working as I wanted, considering that I've configured B to use this option. The projects I put at "Trigger parameterized build on other projects" are always considered DOWNSTREAM projects. I think they should somehow be UPSTREAM projects.

Can someone provide me an easy, step-by-step, way to make B launch A before anything?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

In your case *A* **is** downstream with respect to *B* since *B* launches *A*. If you have hard time accepting it just consider it a naming convention :) It looks like you are doing everything right: *B* should launch *A* via the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) as a build-step (not post-build step), wait for it, and fail if *A* fails (the plugin provides all these features). If everything is OK - continue with other build steps of *B*.

**Important note**: the above applies to Jenkins, not necessarily Hudson. I do not know if the plugin is compatible with Hudson since v2.4, the functionality described here first appears in v2.9

Comment: Thanks, pal. My company uses Hudson... I'm going to check if v2..9 works with it.

Comment: Hudson could not get to it, so I created another job and just called everything there, in the order I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

After checking the Hudson x Jenkins issue, I found out the Parameterized Trigger Plugin only gives this functionality with Jenkins. I created some Groovy scripts and called them as the build steps before the compilation I wanted.